# Where do other programming languages fit in Windows 8 development model?

Tags: windows, languages, windows-8

Today, Windows applications can be developed in numerous languages and frameworks. But in the upcoming Windows 8, with the introduction of WinRT, the development model is going change at a large scale. So, where do other programming languages fit in this model?

Comment: Same way they always have, Windows RT is only half of windows 8. Alot of languages run on .net, so you are probably asking about running something like java in RT.. well you'll need a new UI library for 1.

Comment: Is this question a bit premature?  There really hasn't been time for much WinRT development to happen, and without experience (preferably on a semi-final version) it will be hard to predict these things.

Comment: See the diagram here - http://openlightgroup.net/Blog/tabid/58/EntryId/187/Here-is-where-I-am-at-on-the-Silverlight-is-dead-thing.aspx

Comment: What "Other"?  It would help if you defined what you consider "core".

Comment: "Other" can be defined as any non-.net language except C++ and Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinRT is only part of Windows 8. If you have an application that runs on Windows 7, it will run on Windows 8 (desktop mode) regardless of the tool and language you use. This is true for all the Windows 8 installations that currently exist. It may not be true for ARM installations, if your tool can't target that instruction set. I have heard speculation that some SKUs of Windows 8 might be Metro only, meaning your desktop mode app wouldn't run on those. But for what we have in our hands today, all languages and all tools can still play.

If you want to adopt Metro, because you like the design paradigm, then you might want to switch to one of the four languages you can write Metro apps in. But don't confuse that with all of Windows 8.

Answer (score 2):

> The .NET Framework and the Common Language Runtime (CLR) is integrated
>   into WinRT as a subplatform... WinRT supports XAML-based .NET Metro-style applications which are
>   primarily written in C# and VB.NET. Although not yet officially
>   supported, programs can also be written in other .NET languages.
>
> Classes defined in WinRT components that are built in managed .NET languages must be declared as `sealed`... Members that interface with other language must have a signature with WinRT types or a managed type that is convertible to these.
>
> Native C++ is a first-class citizen of the WinRT-platform.  The language has a number of extensions that enable integration with the platform and its type system.
>
> The "Chakra" JavaScript engine which was developed for Internet Explorer 9 integrates with WinRT. That makes JavaScript a first-class citizen in the WinRT ecosystem.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Runtime

Answer (score 2):

Native C++ a first-class citizen! Well, those of us who have stuck with C++ (and perhaps cross-platform) through the years have always felt so - and even more so now with C++11 (big thanks to all the contributors)!!. Yes, there were many detractors who thought the language was dead or dying (I've heard the words myself), and maybe at times it seemed we chose the desert route (lower pay, fewer opportunities) rather than accepting the shackles. But now, does anyone else care to join me in saying Hallelujah, we're back, and we've been justified?!:)